# Incoherence in complementary indices extracted from a np.array

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, numpy-ndarray, numpy-random

The problem is very simple, I have a vector of indices from which I want to extract one set randomly chosen and its complement. So I write the following code:

```
import numpy as np    
vec = np.arange(0,25000)
idx = np.random.choice(vec,5000)
idx_r = np.delete(vec,idx)
```

However, when I print the length of vec, idx, and idx_r they do not match. The sum between idx and idx_r return values higher than len(vec). For example, the following code:

```
print(len(idx))
print(len(idx_r))
print(len(idx_r)+len(idx))
print(len(vec))
```

returns:

5000
20462
25462
25000

Python version is 3.8.1 and GCC is 9.2.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `np.random.choice` has a keyword argument `replace`. Its default value is `True`. If you set the value to `False`, I think you will get the desired result.

```
import numpy as np

vec = np.arange(0, 25000)

idx = np.random.choice(vec, 5000, replace=False)

idx_r = np.delete(vec, idx)

print([len(item) for item in (vec, idx, idx_r)])
```

Out:

```
[25000, 5000, 20000]
```

However, `numpy.random.choice` with `replace=False` is extremely inefficient due to poor implementation choices they're stuck with for backward compatibility - it generates a permutation of the whole input just to take a small sample. You should use the new [Generator API](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.Generator.choice.html#numpy.random.Generator.choice) instead, which doesn't have this issue:

```
rng = np.random.default_rng()

idx = rng.choice(vec, 5000, replace=False)
```

Comment: You're welcome. I'm just learning Numpy myself. Thanks for posting this. I didn't know about the methods you are using until now. Please mark it as the correct answer if it solved your issue.